# Is there a Commonwealth nation that practices presidential form of government?

Tags: president, form-of-government, commonwealth

What I want to know is countries like [Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Canada), [Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Australia) and [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_India), which are all Commonwealth nations, have adopted a parliamentarian system like [UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_the_United_Kingdom), is there a country that was Commonwealth nation but adopted to presidential form of government?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Botswana, Cameroon, Cyprus, Gabon, Gambia, Ghana, Guyana, Kenya, Kiribati, Malawi, Mozambique, Namibia, Sri Lanka, Maldives, Nauru, Nigeria, Rwanda, Seychelles, Sierra Leone, South Africa, Tanzania, Togo, Uganda, and Zambia all operate under an executive presidency without a Westminster-style parliament - so about half of all the 56 countries in the Commonwealth.

Zimbabwe also has a presidential system, and is currently in the process of re-joining the organisation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Barbados
2. Botswana
3. Cameroon
4. Cyprus
5. Dominica
6. Gabon
7. Gambia
8. Ghana
9. Kenya
10. Kiribati
11. Malawi
12. Malta
13. Mauritius
14. Maldives
15. Namibia
16. Nauru
17. Nigeria
18. Rwanda
19. Seychelles
20. Sierra Leone
21. South Africa
22. Trinidad and Tobago
23. Tanzania
24. Togo
25. Guayana
26. Uganda
27. Mozambique
28. Sri Lanka
29. Vanuatu
30. Zambia